# Git branch showing in remote branch list even after deleting

Tags: git, branch

I have deleted and pushed a branch, but it is still showing in `branch -r` for other users:

```
serverAlpha $ git push origin --delete origin/issue186
serverAlpha $ git push

serverBeta $ git pull
serverBeta $ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/issue186
  origin/master
```

I am aware of `git remote prune origin` however each other user would have to run this. How might I remove the branch such that other users see that it was removed? I cannot expect nor even communicate to all others to prune, and I don't want anybody else basing work off that branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can't. Some operations are simply local in Git.

### git-branch vs. git-ls-remote

The `git branch` command operates on local refs. The `-r` flag simply restricts output to remote-tracking branches, but it doesn't talk to the remote directly. On the other hand, `git ls-remote` will actually show refs from the remote, rather than the local repository.

### Removing Someone Else's Refs

You can't do this with Git. The whole idea of a distributed VCS is that state can exist in a non-centralized way. What this means in your case is that refs on someone's desktop may not match the refs in some bare repository on a defined remote.

Would you want someone else to be able to delete a working branch on your desktop? Probably not. Since Git doesn't allow this, you don't need to lose any sleep over it.

The best you can do is remove the branch from the server. If, as you say, you "can't communicate" with others who have already cloned the work, then there's nothing you can do about it except revert or rebase any work that is based on that branch if/when that work is committed to some mainline branch.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove other people's branches. They are theirs, even the remote-tracking ones.

Their remote-tracking branches will be deleted the next time they fetch from the remote where you deleted branches, provided they use the -p (--prune) flag (I usually do).

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of origin and others have already pulled from it you're out of luck.

However, for your use case I would simply make a new commit to the origin/master branch removing all existing files and adding a README that points the users to the correct policy/branches that should be used.

In that way there isn't a fetch issue for previous collaborators that used the branch and it is very clear how collaborators who may have used origin/master before should proceed.